# Python module to convert from document to html

Tags: python

Is there any python package which converts the uploaded Ms Word document to html content.As in my application am uploading a document and i want to convert it into html

any suggestion o nthis will help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could call [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) from within Python.